# Removed AdMob from source code, but it's still showing an empty space at bottom in app Android Studio

Tags: java, android, admob

I have removed AdMob from my source code of Android Studio, but still, it's showing an empty space at the bottom in the app.

It's always occupying an empty space at the bottom. I do not know how to make that bottom space disappear completely and show a normal preview of the app without ads.

How can I do this?

Here is  the code.

**Mainactivity.java**

```
package com.dshgh.webview;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;

import com.dshgh.webview.Fragments.WebViewFragment;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    RelativeLayout rel_layout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //ButterKnife.bind(this);
        rel_layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel_layout);
        // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        WebViewFragment webViewFragment = new WebViewFragment();
        bundle.putString("url", Config.homeUrl);
        webViewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        loadFragment(webViewFragment, false, "webViewFragment");
        try {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
            Log.d("notification Data", message + url);
            if (url.length() > 0) {
                bundle.putString("url", url);
                webViewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                loadFragment(webViewFragment, false, "webViewFragment");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("error notification data", e.toString());
        }
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        displayFirebaseRegId();
    }


    private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
        String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);

        Log.e("FCM", "Firebase reg id: " + regId);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
            //txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id: " + regId);
        }
        else
            Log.d("Firebase", "Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("webViewFragment");
        if(fragment != null && fragment instanceof WebViewFragment) {
            if(((WebViewFragment) fragment).onBackPressed()) {
                if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                    return;
                }

                this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Press back once more to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(rel_layout, "Press back once more to exit", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                snackbar.show();

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    }

    public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean bool) {
        loadFragment(fragment, bool, null);
    }

    public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean bool, String TAG) {
        showAds();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(TAG == null) {
            transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
        }else {
            transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, TAG);
        }
        if (bool)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("webViewFragment");
        if(fragment != null && fragment instanceof WebViewFragment) {
            ((WebViewFragment)fragment).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    }

    public void hideAds() {

    }

    public void showAds() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your layout specification?

Comment: I think you need to remove hideAds() and showAds() methods from your activity as well as remove Admob from your XML as well if not removed already.

Comment: @JayMungara I tried the method you told but its giving me some errors like "cannot find hide() and show() " and also showing errors about lint when I try to remove <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView......./> ... whats can be issue ?

Comment: check that if you have removed dependency from build.gradle file from your app and project level modules.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to remove <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView......./> from your XML page.

Please remove it.

Comment: There is no "<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView......./>" found on androidManifest.xml file. any other solution please ?